# Calling the sub class method from super class isn't best practice?

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a project where we have an abstract class(`BaseConverter`) with one abstract method(`convert()`) and few concrete methods. One important concrete method is `invokeConverter()` which will basically call the `convert()` method implemented in the subclass.

While our code is being reviewed by other guy, he told that, subclass methods shouldn't be called from superclass and he told it is not best practice. Below is our class structure. Can someone please tell whether this isn't a right way to do?

```
@Named
public abstract class BaseConverter{ 

     @Inject
     private ConversionDriver conversionDriver;//this class is responsible to return the correct subclass object based on the type

     protected abstract String convert(Object toConvert); 

     public String invokeConverter(ConverterType type, Object toConvert){
       conversionDriver.getConverter(type).convert(toConvert);//getConverter() return the subclass object based on the type
     } 
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the subclass method. You are just calling the overridden method of the superclass. And that is one of the reasons for having abstract methods in first place. I don't know how this will be bad practice.

Comment: @Codebender, thanks.. yes, i justified with the same answer but that guy isn't convinced and asked us to change the structure.

Comment: ask that guy....let him explain as he knows your code well.

Comment: I think perhaps the problem is that `invokeConverter` seems to do the work of a static method rather than an instance method, in that it retrieves some object to do the conversion. This means basically a subclass instance will have to be created and then create another instance based on the type. The template method should work directly with the current instance assuming it's the "right instance" and a static method should do the selection of correct subclass.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, this is the exact change i am making after reading the template pattern. I am moving the `private ConversionDriver conversionDriver;` to the calling class, so that, the `convert()` will be called for the currect instance. thanks much.

Comment: The part that isn't best practice is where you are using base classes and subclasses. Inheritance is widely frowned upon these days. If you do use inheritance though, then what you are doing is acceptable.

Comment: Note aside: I think a return statement for `invokeConverter` is missing.

Comment: @DavidArno I think that's a ridiculous thing to say.  Sure, there's a definite tendency to overuse inheritance these days.  But inheritance can be very useful; and it certainly has its place. To say that it's always bad practice shows a deep lack of understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually a design pattern called *Template Method* by GoF. However, you should not over apply it as it favors inheritance over composition.

> Define the skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some
>   steps to subclasses. Template Method lets subclasses redefine certain
>   steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure.

You'll find this pattern implemented in many known frameworks and plugins. But, you should consider different patterns like the Strategy or the Decorator in some cases.

For instance, while Strategy pattern uses delegation to vary the whole algorithm, Template Method uses the defamed inheritance to vary a specific part of an algorithm. Strategy also modifies the logic of individual objects at run-time, while the Template Method modifies the logic of the entire class at compile-time by subclassing.

---

Regarding "best practice" - it is a controversial term. I believe that the Template Method should be replaced in favor of a better design pattern when the code base grows and refactoring for a better complexity is needed.

But sometimes it is the best solution for your needs. For example, you might have `doExecute()` method and would like other programmers to extend your class (whilst not modifying it), so you let them hook into the parts of your code providing a `beforeExecute()` method. Mature system would maybe include an event dispatcher capabilities if we talked about combination of various objects.

Comment: This is kind of true; but in the OP's example, they're actually doing something rather different - they're calling the template method on a separate instance.  Not really the "template method" design pattern at all, and somewhat confusing.  I'd have to agree with the reviewer.

Comment: agree @DavidWallace, I am moving the private ConversionDriver conversionDriver; to the calling class, so that, the convert() will be called for the currect instance. thanks much.

Comment: Good point @DavidWallace. I mostly related to the title of this question. Praki, your refactoring is great and would implement this pattern correctly.

Comment: Definite downvote for suggesting that inheritance and the Template Method anti-pattern are in any way "best practice".

Comment: @DavidArno, I think it is a little bit controversial. We should favor composition over inheritance. However, sometimes it is smarter to use inheritance. Template Method is a technique which is well known and therefore readable for most programmers. Does it make it an anti pattern? What would you use instead of the Method pattern? There are always several ways to do same things. But for my opinion, the most decoupled solution is not necessarily the smartest in each case. Readability and maintainability are.

Comment: @DavidArno Template method is not an anti-pattern.  It appears in all good books on design patterns.  And in certain cases, it is definitely "best practice" - it's widely used by some very experienced, very expert software designers.

Comment: @TechWisdom. You are using an "appeal to authority" fallacy there. IMO those books inherently aren't good as they are advocating bad practice. A number of GoF patterns, such as Singleton, Service Locator and Template, are all now widely recognised as anti-patterns.

Comment: @DavidArno I can't fully understand you. As David Wallace said, the Template Method has its place. Moreover, I edited to mention its possible drawbacks such as contradicting "favor composition over inheritance" idea. I also mentioned some other design patterns to address this. GoF is not a bible, but it definitively has some things to offer or at least to be referred. Regarding Singletons and Service Locators, you are right. I always recommend to use DiC instead, but that's another issue.

Comment: @DavidArno ‘A number of GoF patterns, such as Singleton, Service Locator and Template, are all now widely recognised as anti-patterns.’ FYI, Service Locator is *not* a GoF design pattern.

Comment: @Maggyero, oh you are right. I hadn't released its origins were with J2EE, rather than as a C++ missing feature work-around. Thanks for putting me right.